# Calling `Rscript` from QGIS Python Console / QGIS Plugin not working

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, r, subprocess

I want to run a `RScript` that plots some data which is fetched by a QGIS Plugin. However it returns a non zero-exist status and breaks (when running with `subprocess.check_call`) or just skips the command when calling `subprocess.call` / `subprocess.Popen`.

Things I've done so far:

**check_call:**

```
script_filename = "/myRscript/that/plots/some/stuff.R"
csvpath = "/path/of/csvdata.csv"
output_dir = "/output/directory"
p1 = subprocess.check_call(['/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Rscript', script_filename, "-f", csvpath, "-o", output_dir], shell=False)
```

returns following Error:

```
>>> subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Rscript', '(...)createProfile.R', '-f', '(...)profile_data.csv', '-o', '(...)4 MASTERARBEIT']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

**Popen**:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Rscript', script_filename, "-f", csvpath, "-o", output_dir], shell=False)
p1.wait()
>>> 1
```

However, the calls work fine when I try to call them from a standard python session outside of QGIS. What is even more irritating is that a command like `subprocess.check_call(['open', output_dir], shell=False)`works inside QGIS.

BTW, I'm on Mac OS X High Sierra and QGIS 3.2.0 Bonn / Python 3.6.

Comment: It has run the Rscript executable but that script has returned with an error status code. Is there anything in the output directory?

Comment: No unfortunately not. It seems that the QGIS Python version somehow behaves differently to the normal system version...

Comment: Can you run a trivial R script, called with no options? eg `subprocess.check_call(["Rscript","msg.R"])` where `msg.R` contains `message("hello")`? With everything in the right directory of course...

Comment: This returns `exit status 2`...however I'm not sure if I'm referencing the file correctly. I just copied it to my plugins folder where all the plugin's python scripts located.

Comment: Furthermore I have to call `Rscript` by it's full path, like: `subprocess.check_call(["/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Rscript", "msg.R"])` otherwise it returns that `Rscript` is not found.

Comment: Give the full path to `msg.R`. Exit status 2 happens if Rscript doesn't find its argument.

Comment: Ok I tried that and it seems to work, however I did not see any message from `R`.

Comment: I additionally changed my R Script to ignore the command line arguments and switched to fixed paths on my system, **which is working so far**. Still strange why it doesn't accept the arguments when they come from qgis python but accepts them if they come from the system python version...

Comment: @Valentin: Can you post your own answer to help future readers? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestions and help of @Spacedman I was able to find a way to solve the problem. I had to modify the processing of my R command line arguments inside the R script and changed it to following:

**R Script `msg.R`:**

```
library("optparse")

option_list = list(
  make_option(c("-f", "--file"), type="character", default="/Users/Valentin/Desktop", 
              help="dataset file name", metavar="character")
); 

opt_parser = OptionParser(option_list=option_list);
opt = parse_args(opt_parser);
if (is.null(opt$file)){
  print_help(opt_parser)
  stop("At least one argument must be supplied (input file)", call=FALSE)
}

print(opt$file)
fileConn<-file(opt$file)
writeLines(c("Hello","World"), fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

The QGIS / Python side looks like this:

**`main_plugin_file.py`**:

```
# get filename of python file in the plugin, get the directory of it and append the msgR file 
pyfile = os.path.realpath(__file__)
plugin_folder = os.path.normpath(pyfile.replace(os.path.basename(pyfile),""))
msgR_path = os.path.join(plugin_folder,"msg.R") # msg.R is in the same folder as the plugin
outpath = os.path.join(output_dir, "thisworksnow.txt")

#actual call to the R script, Note: I had to supply an absolute path to Rscript
subprocess.check_call(["/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Rscript",msgR_path, "-f", outpath])
```

**Note:** To supply an absolute path to `Rscript` is not perfect and as a consequence not transferable to other OS Configurations. But maybe somebody else got a clever solution for that as well (e.g. by env variables or so).